# How to do different registration forms according to User type. User type should be established before registration itself

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to make different registration forms according to different User types. I`ve created a custom User, which can be either Customer or Seller, like this:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    class UserTypeChoices(models.TextChoices):
        Customer = 'Customer', _('Customer')
        Seller = 'Seller', _('Seller')
     
    type = models.CharField(
        max_length=8,
        choices=UserTypeChoices.choices,
    )
```

My idea is that at first, a person, who visites my website should choose his type, and after that he can register according to it`s type. Sellers should have phone numbers as USERNAME_FIELD, while Customers should have email. I know that I will have to write custom backend for this thing, yet still this is what I want to do.

I`ve decided to do two different forms for this: First one with only type field, which should redirect to a form with normal registration. This first form looks like this:

```
class UserTypeForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ["type"]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self._meta.model.USERNAME_FIELD in self.fields:
            self.fields[self._meta.model.USERNAME_FIELD].widget.attrs[
                "autofocus"
            ] = True
        del self.fields["password1"]
        del self.fields["password2"]

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        return user
```

And here is where I`ve stopped right now, as it gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\Hillel\VolunteeringHub\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\Python\Hillel\VolunteeringHub\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\Hillel\VolunteeringHub\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 103, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\Hillel\VolunteeringHub\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 142, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\Hillel\VolunteeringHub\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 184, in post
    return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\Hillel\VolunteeringHub\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py", line 153, in post
    return self.form_valid(form)
  File "D:\Python\Hillel\VolunteeringHub\src\accounts\views.py", line 21, in form_valid
    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
  File "D:\Python\Hillel\VolunteeringHub\src\accounts\forms.py", line 29, in save
    user = super().save(commit=False)
  File "D:\Python\Hillel\VolunteeringHub\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py", line 141, in save
    user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
KeyError: 'password1'
```

And here is my views.py also:

```
from django.shortcuts import render  # NOQA

# Create your views here.
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import CreateView, TemplateView

from accounts.forms import RegistrationForm, UserTypeForm


class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "index/index.html"


class UserTypeChoice(CreateView):
    form_class = UserTypeForm
    template_name = "registration/user_type_choice.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy("accounts:registration")

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.is_active = False

        return super().form_valid(form)


class Registration(CreateView):
    form_class = RegistrationForm
    template_name = "registration/user_form.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy("config:core")

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.is_active = False
        self.object.save()

        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Even though I have commit=False here, it doesn`t allow me to save user without password.

So my question is how can I save this form, so the view will redirect to one or another registration form.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you add `views.py`  to your question  ?

Comment: Sure, added it to the question!